# How to use vars from UDF's in main()? (Python)

Tags: python, undefined, user-defined-functions

So Here's my problem, I'm coding a game in Python and I'm trying to implement a combat system, but in order to do that, I need to print a variable from a user defined function I've created. Every time I try to run the code though, it just tells me the variable (acten) is not defined, even though I've included the UDF in the main. How do I get this to work?

```
def en_spawn():

enstype = random.randint(1,100)
if enstype >= 99:
    enstype = "Aelon, the Fallen"
else:
    if enstype >= 98:
        enstype = "Mael, the Trapped"
    else:
        if enstype >= 97:
            enstype = "Ish Ash, the Tormented"
        else:
            if enstype >= 96:
                enstype = "Farr, the Defeated"
            else:
                if enstype >= 86:
                    enstype = "Bloodthirsty"
                else:
                    if enstype >= 45:
                        enstype = "Vengeful"
                    else:
                        if enstype >= 15:
                            enstype = "Tranquil"
                        else:
                            if enstype >= 0:
                                enstype = "Harmless"


entype = random.randint(1,100)
if entype >= 97:
    entype = " Demon"
else:
  if entype >= 92:
      entype = " Damned"
  else:
      if entype >= 80:
          entype = " Familiar"
      else:
          if entype >= 50:
              entype = " Spirit"
          else:
              if entype >= 0:
                  entype = " Undead"

if enstype == "Aelon, the Fallen":
    entype = " King"

sec_boss = random.randint(1,1000)
if enstype == "Aelon, the Fallen":
    if sec_boss >= 976:
        enstype = "All"
        entype = ""
    else:
        if sec_boss >= 779:
            enstype = "Aelon, the Redeemed"
            entype = ""

acten= enstype+entype
```

def main():

```
en_spawn()
print(acten)
```

main()

Comment: try `return acten`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to return the value.
so try:

```
return acten
```

in `main`:

```
val = en_spawn()
print val
```